# Editing and Capturing new option from optionMenu Tkinter

Tags: for-loop, tkinter, optionmenu

I created a list of optionMenus via a for loop. I need to tie my optionMenu selection to the optionMenu it came from. The for loop, I think, is making it so I am unable to tie the two values together.

```
def get_selection(choice):
    popUp_list.append(choice)

if num >= 1 and num <5:
    for num in range(1,5):
        choice = StringVar(root2)
        choices = {'Application', 'File', 'Website'}
        choice.set('Choose Type')

        popUpMenu = OptionMenu(root2, choice, *choices, command = Controller.get_selection)
        popUpMenu.grid(row=num, column=0)
```

**I know it would be easier to hard code the option menus, but for reasons I don't want to get in to, the for loop is necessary. Not for this part specifically, but for another part of my code. It's just easier to use this example here.**

When an option is selected from the menus, I am able to pull the values and that works great.  However, if a user makes a first selection and then wants to update their selection, I have no way to capture that.  It creates a "new" selection, not tied to the optionMenu. So the new option does not **replace** the old option.  It just creates a new selection.

Is there a way to pass the popUpMenu number through the Controller .get_selection function?  When trying to pass another variable doing something on the lines of:

```
def get_selection(choice, num):
    popUp_list.append(choice)
    print(num)
popUpMenu = OptionMenu(root2, choice, *choices, command = lambda: Controller.get_selection(choice, num))
```

I get the error below and I'm not able to get the option selection. I'm not sure what to put as the first value.  Inputting choice does not work.

self.__callback(self.__value, *args)
TypeError: () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this.  I updated my code to :

```
    if num >= 1 and num <5:
        for num in range(1,5):
            choice = StringVar(root2)
            choices = {'Application', 'File', 'Website'}
            choice.set('Choose Type')


            popUpMenu = OptionMenu(root2, choice, *choices, command = lambda choice = choice, num = num: (Controller.get_selection(choice, num)))
```

So, making your command statement like:
**command = lambda choice = choice, num = num: (Controller.get_selection(choice, num)))**

allows you to pass variables into your function.